# Inverse set of a many to 1 where not all records exist in one table

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

TSQL/Access

I am trying to return the inverse of the result set....

```
SELECT Units.Unit_ID
FROM Units
WHERE (((Units.[Unit_ID]) In (SELECT Objects.Unit_ID FROM Objects)));
```

This returns the full set above plus the single additional record I would have expected....

```
SELECT Units.Unit_ID
FROM Units
WHERE (((Units.[Unit_ID]) not In (SELECT Objects.Unit_ID FROM Objects)));
```

Units has abandon records that do not exist in Objects. Many Objects to 1 Units. But some units do not exist in Objects. That is the result set I am looking for.

**Data sample set:**

Objects
Unit_ID
1
1
1
2
2
4
5
56
78

Units
Unit_ID
1
2
3
4
5
56
78

Result set should be:  3

I do not want to return values that are in both tables.

Comment: So what is the problem? the inverse for `IN` is `NOT IN` should work fine

Comment: Those queries are the inverse of each other.  Are you saying there are records that are in _both_ results? Can you provide sample data and output?

Comment: Both queries return the full table results, the second includes the abandon record I am looking for.

Comment: just a thought, maybe you have too many brackets try using less: (Units.[Unit_ID] not In (SELECT Objects.Unit_ID FROM Objects));

Comment: brackets did not change anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Curious, what does this return:

```
SELECT Units.Unit_ID
FROM Units
LEFT JOIN Objects ON Objects.Unit_ID = Units.[Unit_ID]
WHERE Objects.Unit_ID IS NULL
```

OR

```
SELECT Units.Unit_ID
FROM Units
LEFT JOIN Objects ON Objects.Unit_ID = Units.[Unit_ID]
GROUP BY Units.Unit_ID
HAVING COUNT(Objects.Unit_ID) = 0
```

Comment: The full list, all records. I actually started this with a left join/

Comment: How about: SELECT Units.Unit_ID
FROM Units
LEFT JOIN Objects ON Objects.Unit_ID = Units.[Unit_ID]
GROUP BY Units.Unit_ID
HAVING COUNT(Objects.Unit_ID) = 0

Comment: Your first query in your answer post worked correctly. Thank you.